# Exception has occurred: ImportError Vscode While Debugging

Tags: python, django, debugging, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I am trying to try the debug tool in my vs code I am totally new to vs code and I am getting an error such as this when I run it
[ERROR MESSAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RDr8.png) I have a folder called .vscode with a launch.json file `

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
        "name": "Python: Django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\myPro\\manage.py",
        "args": [
            "runserver"
        ],
        "django": true,
        "justMyCode": true
    }
    ]

}
```

I watched a lot of videos on youtube and I see people who have settings.json in there .vscode file.

WHAT I HAVE DONE:

I have downloaded django == 3.25

I have downloaded python == 3.10.4

IN a virtual environment my environment works perfectly fine its just that I can find the reason to this problem I would really appreciate it if someone can help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Ctrl + Shift + P` and the option "Select Python Interpreter", then select the one in which the environment is. This should have VSCode running in the same environment.

Answer (score 0):

[Please change your debug settings to your Virtual Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQNZi.png)
Open .py file and then debug it.
You may have to restart vscode